# Chrome CSS border issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I've found some very strange behaviour with Chrome with respect to the following CSS...

CSS:

```css
table.addressBody {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
table.addressBody tr td {
    padding:    4px;
    width:      40%;
    min-width:  40%;
    max-width:  40%;
    border:     none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
table.addressBody tr td.left, table.addressBody tr td.right {
    background-color: White;
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
}
table.addressBody tr td.centre {
    width:      20%;
    min-width:  20%;
    max-width:  20%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="fitWidth centre">
    <strong>Mr Smith</strong><br />
    29/05/2014 11:17:00 - Department, Site
</div>
<table class="addressBody">
    <tr>
        <td class="left">
            <select name="ctl00$phBody$repPatients$ctl01$ddlPickup" id="ctl00_phBody_repPatients_ctl01_ddlPickup"></select>
        </td>
        <td class="centre" style="border: none;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="right">
            <select name="ctl00$phBody$repPatients$ctl01$ddlDest" id="ctl00_phBody_repPatients_ctl01_ddlDest"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="leftShadow" colspan="2">
            <img src="../img/other/bottomShadowLt.png" alt="Shadow" />
        </td>
        <td class="rightShadow">
            <img src="../img/other/bottomShadowRt.png" alt="Shadow" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qot28kjd/1/))

The problem is the centre cell of the table which has a bottom border, despite the fact that I haven't actually specified that there should be one.  I've tried the same code in both IE and FF and both produce the desired result (two outer cells with borders and the inner without).

I have also tried coding the CSS in turn for each border on all of the cells, but as soon as I code the `#left` cell `bottom-border` the centre cell is also bordered on the bottom.  Also, notice in relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647201/strange-css-border-issue-in-chrome) there is no border collapse in the code (unless it's part of Fiddle itself).

Can anyone spot anything obvious that I've missed or know of any bug with Chrome that has a workaround?

**-- EDIT --**

[image: Example of problem]

Comment: Hint: Don't use tables for layouts.

Comment: The table was for displaying data that is purely tabular.  @ConorWright and MatthewG: the bottom border was left in there as an error of copying and pasting the code.

Comment: After modifying the obvious mistake out in Fiddle the the styling does work, however, there is something amiss still as on my PC the styling doesn't seem to be producing the goods.

Comment: After going back to the [post mentioned above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647201/strange-css-border-issue-in-chrome), it seems that the `border-collapse` setting could be responsible, despite (as pointed out by Conor, below) there being some debugging code in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange CSS Border Issue in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647201/strange-css-border-issue-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my post is, in fact, a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647201/strange-css-border-issue-in-chrome), and so, if you wish to close it, please feel free.

Answer (score 1):

But you did specify that it have a bottom border:

```
table.addressBody tr td.centre {
    width:      20%;
    min-width:  20%;
    max-width:  20%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #aaa; <---
    text-align: center;
}
```